# Bouquet of pink roses not blooming

Tags: roses

I hastily bought a bouquet of pink roses yesterday, but they haven't bloomed yet. The flowers are in my room right now, and I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to make them bloom?

Comment: Have you trimmed the stem ends, and stuck the flowers in a vase containing water? If so, waiting *usually* produces results.

Comment: no, not yet. i'll do that today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cut at least 1-2" off the ends, at an angle but DO IT UNDERWATER!  Then quickly put into the vase filled with PLAIN water, no additives.

Otherwise, you will probably get air bubbles in the stem just below the rose head and the rose will wilt.  No biggie.  I'd just dry the roses and make a dried arrangement.

If you don't see any wilting you should see the rose heads open.  Using your thumb and a finger, squeeze the head of a rose.  It should feel very firm, hard and substantial.  If it feels empty, soft, squishy...it might not open, or it will open briefly then fall apart quickly.  When you shop for roses always give them this little test before you buy.

As soon as you get them home, cut the ends UNDER WATER and arrange in a vase with pure water.  I never let my roses bloom completely or rather get to the point the petals are falling off.  Dried roses are wonderful and can last for years. Dry them and keep them out of direct sunlight.  You can spray with hairspray to make them last longer and/or clean/refresh the dried rose.

Are these spray roses or tea roses?